# What's the pythonic way of this code?

Tags: python, dataframe

## Get Selected Table by checking author name ( python )

```
df_temp = df_concat_year[(
    df_concat_year[0].isin([chk_at])|
    df_concat_year[1].isin([chk_at])|
    df_concat_year[2].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[3].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[4].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[5].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[6].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[7].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[8].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[9].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[10].isin([chk_at])|
    df_concat_year[11].isin([chk_at])| 
    df_concat_year[12].isin([chk_at])|
    df_concat_year[13].isin([chk_at]))]
```

I want to get the selected DataFrame which contains a Certain String(chk_at)
original DataFrame is 'df_concat_year' contains columns of 0 ~ 11 or 0 ~ 13 more 
original DataFrame Columns name & length may change 
How I can get a easy way to get the selected DF

I Use below code but it doesn't work

```
`df_temp = df_concat_year[(df_concat_year.iloc[:,17:].isin([chk_at]))]`
```

which I tried to get the after 17-columns

df_concat_year contains below data 
 ["df_concat_year"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl5sQ.png)

Comment: What is the content of your dataframe? Can you give example data?

Comment: I add the dataframe image. Thank you

Comment: what about `chk_at in df_concat_year`? This will check if `chk_at` is present in any of the `df_concat_year` elements, which is equivalent to all your `or` conditions.

Comment: Thank your comment. I want to use more concise way to check and then the columns length will be extended.